# How to merge vertices by distance or delete faces with zero area?

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, edges

There is that mesh where we can see there are faces on the edges with zero area.

[image]

I guess there should be a function to remove faces with zero area or merge vertices/edge with distance threshold (like in Maya).

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/clean-up-vertices-edges-with-no-faces

Comment: Also the basic `W` > *Remove Doubles* is pretty well known