# Dissolve lonely vertices. Blender 2.8

Tags: vertices

I want to dissolve every vertex which does not connected with another vertex ( vertex which has no connection with any vertex ). How can i do that.

Comment: You'll find some answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/clean-up-vertices-edges-with-no-faces   for example Select > Select All By Trait > Loose Geometry, or select one lonely vertex and shift G > Amount of Connecting Edges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In edit mode Select all of the geometry <kbd>a</kbd>. Choose Mesh > Clean Up > Delete Loose

[image]

[image]